# How to stop/close SignalR service

Tags: signalr, visual-studio-2013

I just upgrade from VS2010 express to VS2013 express and open my project.
I found the SignalR is running but I don't need it.Firebug is filling with SignalR message.I take long time to search how to stop/close it,but I can't find it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

On your toolbar in between the debug and the browser choice there is a button called browser link - click it and de-select the "Enable browser link" and you should be good to go...

Comment: Thanks! I also found the "Enable browser link" screen shot http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Comment: Part of "Standard" toolbar

Comment: Hallelujah!!!! Turning this off my site now updates instantly when I do a recompile and refresh the browser.  It was taking up to a minute to figure out how to render my site sometimes.  Thanks

Comment: In VS2015, it is also very well hidden in the drop down of the "refresh browser link" icon next to the play-and-browser-choice button. which looks almost identical to the restart button (arrow orientation left/right). CSS auto sync (which is a blessing) unfortunately depends on the browser link feature, so you can't keep just that enabled and turn off the rest.