# How to stop/close SignalR service in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: signalr, visual-studio-2015

How to stop or disable SignalR service in Visual Studio 2015.

UI has changed since 2013, so the following is not applicable to VS 2015 ([How to stop/close SignalR service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092481/how-to-stop-close-signalr-service))

Answer (score 3):

Right click on menu and select "Standard" toolbar. Browser Link button will have "Enable browser link" checkbox.

Video on how to do it

http://screencast.com/t/FLaQHBH0Oy7

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can open up the Browser Link Dashboard. `View -> Other Windows -> Browser Link Dashboard`